# auth with csrf token and cookie for my rest client not working

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

## Background

I have one REST API which is calling third party rest API using resttemplate which requires csrf-token and cookie for auth,i am hard coding the same csrf-token in my local rest API and trying to hit the controller url but its failing... 
I have set csrf-token and cookie fetched from the web for auth but its giving me No CSRF token was found.

```
public HttpHeaders buildHttpHeaders() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("csrf_token", csrf_token);
    headers.set("Cookie", cookie);

    return headers;
}
```

## postman response

```
   {
    "data": {
        "ArchiveUser": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "No CSRF token was found!",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 39
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "ArchiveUser"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class UserController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

   @RequestMapping(value="/create" ,method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
   public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest createUserRequest){

       return userService.createUser(createUserRequest);
   }
}
```

## UserService

```
@Value("${admin.csrf_token}")
private String csrf_token;

@Value("${admin.Cookie}")
private String cookie;

public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) {
        createUserRequest.setQuery(createQueryString);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        logger.debug(g.toJson(createUserRequest));

        HttpEntity<CreateUserRequest> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<CreateUserRequest>(createUserRequest,
                buildHttpHeaders());
        logger.debug("httpenetity" + requestEntity);

        ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                String.class);
        return response;
    }

public HttpHeaders buildHttpHeaders() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("csrf_token", csrf_token);
        headers.set("Cookie", cookie);

        return headers;
    }
```

## yml input

admin:
    csrf_token: xxxxx
    Cookie: _csrf=xxxxxx

I am badly stuck here.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the name of the header with csrf token value shoud be named 'x-csrf-token'

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the name of the header with csrf token value shoud be named 'x-csrf-token'

Comment: does that cause any issue because the name which i got from the web was csrf_token only and so m setting same,and also if i hit the third party url directly through postman it's not causing any issue ,i am getting valid response but the same not working with my API please help

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing your code, one thing I can say, if it works from postman and not from your code, then the problem must be related to your code

Comment: plz see code n let me know if u need any other info

Comment: Where is the code which fetch the token?

Comment: m passing it thru header from code perspective i have hardcoded in yml file and getting the values

Comment: Well, this doesn't make sense, you are totally missing here the purpose of the CSRF protection, csrf token only valid for the same session. In short, your code should look as follows:
1. Perform GET call to fetch the token
2. Parse csrf token header
3. Use parsed value for the POST request

Comment: have edited my code and provided with all req info

Comment: Please read my previous comment again

Comment: can u plz guide me wht changes required ,m still new to csrf token

Comment: You have to implement GET call prior to your post call YOU CAN'T use hardcoded value

Comment: is there any way to get the token if i don't have any API given for fetching token?plz provide code snippet if possible

Comment: also the token which is getting generated from the client web app is valid for 48 hrs,so i dont want to fetch it and send again as I am doing just a poc and i have to just establish communication between my API and theirs..so i prefer to have it from the web and use it

Comment: How did you fetch the token in the first place?

Comment: I performed some action on the web and got it

Answer (score 0):

this issue is resolved after re-lloking on my code,there was variable name mismatch